# RCP/SWT/JFace ProgressBar inside Login dialog

Tags: swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I want to show a ProgressBar inside a normal jface Dialog at the start of an Eclipse RCP App.
I have a Login dialog which is shown at the start of the Application, before the Workbench is created:

```
LoginDialog loginDialog = new LoginDialog(null);
loginDialog.setBlockOnOpen(true);
    if (loginDialog.open() != Dialog.OK) {
        display.dispose();
        return IApplication.EXIT_OK;
    }
```

on `LoginDialog.okPressed()` I call the login information. I need to show an `SWT.INDETERMINATE` ProgressBar while the login logic is being done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://tom-eclipse-dev.blogspot.com/2007/06/splash-screen-and-threads.html describes how you can develop a splash login. I managed to adapt it to a Dialog and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried ProgressMonitorDialog? I think this should do the work. It won't work out of the box, but at least you can see how the Progress Bar is implemented. Another way would be to use custom splash screen. [Here](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseRCP/article.html#product_configuratoin) you can see how to create splash with progress bar and afterwards you can customize it with login form.

Comment: Hi aphex. It doesen't work with ProgressMonitorDialog but i got it working after I checked out this tutorial http://tom-eclipse-dev.blogspot.com/2007/06/splash-screen-and-threads.html. The secret is using this doEventLoop method. Thanks for your help.